# Swift - show revealingSplashView when app launches no matter which ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In my app I am using a [revealingSplashView](https://github.com/PiXeL16/RevealingSplashView).

The user can either be logged in so the starting `ViewController` is changed:

```
    class MainNavigationControllerViewController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if isLoggedIn() {
            let homeController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HomeVC")
            viewControllers = [homeController]
        }
    }

    fileprivate func isLoggedIn() -> Bool {
        return UserDefaults.standard.isLoggedIn()
    }
}
```

**Or** the user is not logged in so `FirstLaunchViewController` is being displayed from where the user can log in and get to `MainViewController`.

At the moment I am presenting `revealingSplashView` in `FirstLaunchViewController` like this:

```
let revealingSplashView = RevealingSplashView(iconImage: UIImage(named: "zauberstab")!, iconInitialSize: CGSize(width: 120, height: 120), backgroundColor: .white)

revealingSplashView.startAnimation()
```

The problem is that I also want to have that animation if the user is logged in so `MainViewController` is the starting VC. I know I could just copy the code from `FirstLaunchViewController` to `MainViewController` but that was cause a problem when the user logs in and gets to `MainViewController` the animation is being displayed even though it should only be displayed after the app launches.

Comment: why not just move `revealingSplashView` code in appDelegate in `didFinishLaunch` so it will always get called. If the user is logged in or not.

Comment: how I exactly do I implement this? I tried adding both of the lines in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` but that doesn't do anything

Comment: here is my git: https://github.com/DieGlueckswurst/Wishlist  if that helps

Answer (score 0):

like @chirag90 suggested the solution was to move the code in `AppDelegate` in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` like this:

```
var window: UIWindow?

let revealingSplashView = RevealingSplashView(iconImage: UIImage(named: "zauberstab")!, iconInitialSize: CGSize(width: 120, height: 120), backgroundColor: .white)

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    revealingSplashView.startAnimation()
    window?.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(revealingSplashView)

    return true
}
```

Another problem that came up was how to add `reavelingSplashView` as a `Subview` which was answered by @matt in this question:

[adding Subview in AppDelegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59904854/swift-adding-subview-in-appdelegate/59904926#59904926)

Comment: I don’t get it. Isn’t that exactly what we established back in https://stackoverflow.com/a/59904926/341994? Did you go backwards since then?

Comment: yes it basically is. I didn't know when I asked this question about `didFinishLaunching` . Should I close the other question or link you here ?

Comment: I don’t know :) I think it’s easier to understand if this answer contains a link to the other question.