# Swift - adding Subview in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, appdelegate, subview

I have a problem with [revealingSplashView](https://github.com/PiXeL16/RevealingSplashView). I want it to be shown every time the app launches but it is not being displayed because I have to add it as a `Subview` but how can I do that inside `AppDelegate`?

I tried this but it is not working:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

let revealingSplashView = RevealingSplashView(iconImage: UIImage(named: "zauberstab")!, iconInitialSize: CGSize(width: 120, height: 120), backgroundColor: .white)

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    print("hi")
    revealingSplashView.startAnimation()
    window?.addSubview(revealingSplashView)
    FirebaseApp.configure()

    return true
}
```

Comment: `window?.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(revealingSplashView)`?

Comment: working like a charm, thanks :)

Comment: Cool, I'll give that as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the order of events. You add the splash view. Then the root view controller comes along and gets its view and adds that to the window — covering the splash view.

One workaround is to make the root view controller get its view *now* and put the splash view in *that* view:

```
window?.rootViewController?.view.addSubview(revealingSplashView)
```